# Как сделать, чтобы появление картинки и ссылки были только при наведении конкретно на текст?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши ссылка и сама картинка появлялись, только если наведено конкретно на текст, а не на границы блока слева, справа и т.д.

Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Так](http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/4/)?

HTML

```
<div class="layout">
   <div class="col1">
            <a href="#"><br>&larr; WORK</a>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.col1 {
  text-align:left;
    left: 0; /* Положение левого края */
    right: 50%; /* Положение правого края */
    margin-top:13%;
    font-family: AGHelveticaCyr, 'AGHelveticaCyr';
  font-size: 1.5vw;
    color:#0066cc;
    padding-left:15%;
}

.col1 a:hover{
    display: block;
    background:url(http://www.newportlibraryri.org/npl/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Grass-Border1-200x100.gif)  no-repeat;
  height:5.5vw;
}
```

Comment: Да, практически то, что надо. Не подскажите, как сделать, чтобы картинка начиналась не от края начала текста, а до него, и текст как бы должен быть посередине картинки.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите? Конечный результат какой, это будет вроде раздела меню? Может, так вас устроит http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/9/